# installing ag-grid into existing angular2+ project

Tags: angular

Is there a way to install the ag-grid into an existing project without using the 'seed' they supply here?
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: `npm install ag-grid`

Comment: Thanks! I did more searching and found a nice step by step. I'm following it now and keeping my fingers crossed.
https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Yeah I was gonna link that one as well :) But yeah, you shouldn't run into any trouble with that one, hopefully :P Come back if you have issues.

Comment: No, pretty much a failure. Looks nothing like a grid =(.

Comment: They made a small but fatal flaw in their example code. In the red-component.component.ts file they forgot to add the interpolation for the value. I had to look at the seed to find it.

<span style="color: red">{{ params.value }}</span>

Now it looks good. Thanks, I'm still new to this (desktop app guy).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instruction at:

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0

```
npm i ag-grid --save
npm i ag-grid-angular --save
```

To get the example to work, replace their src/app/red-component/red-component.component.html code with:

```
<span style="color: red">{{ params.value }}</span>
```

Hopefully this will help someone like me wading into js frameworks for the first time.